# How to deserialize WCF message using OperationContract

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-deserialization

I succeeded in building a WCF client generated by svcutil.exe from the WSDL. Using the generated client proxy class I can call the web service of an external service supplier. I also succeeded in coding a message inspector, as I need to log both raw XML request and response as full SOAP message to the database.

For an emergency scenario I also need to be able to "import" a raw XML response. I found many hints on using `XMLSerializer` or deserializing WCF messages based on the message contract.

But how can I deserialize a raw XML response based on an operation contract? For a first test I use one of the logged raw responses, save it to a file and now try to deserialize it to the response type as generated in the client proxy. Somehow I must succeed in calling `DeserializeReply()` from class `ClientOperation`. But how to get there?

I happily accept any help as I'm quite new to WCF...
TIA,
Stefan

This is what I tried after Marc's answer:

```
  public static RatingResult DeserializeResponseFromFile(string path)
  {
     var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(path);
     var message = Message.CreateMessage(xmlReader, int.MaxValue, MessageVersion.Soap11);
     var readerAtBodyContents = message.GetReaderAtBodyContents();
     var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(RatingResult), "RatingResponse", "http://rating.webservice.xxx.de");

     // Error in line 6 position 7. 'EndElement' 'RatingResponse' from namespace
     // 'http://rating.webservice.xxx.de' is not expected.
     // Expecting element 'commonDataField'.
     var wsResult = (RatingResult)dcs.ReadObject(readerAtBodyContents);

     return wsResult;
  }
```

This is part of the logged XML response file, that I'm trying to deserialize to type `RatingResponse`:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="..." xmlns:soapenc="..." xmlns:xsd="..." xmlns:xsi="...">
  <soapenv:Header soapenv:encodingStyle="..." />
  <soapenv:Body soapenv:encodingStyle="...">
    <p933:RatingResponse xmlns:p933="http://rating.webservice.xxx.de">
      <RatingReturn href="#id0" />
    </p933:RatingResponse>
    <multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="..." xsi:type="p878:RatingResult" xmlns:p878="http://output.rating.webservice.xxx.de">
      <commonData href="#id1" />
      <acctData href="#id2" />
      <resultData href="#id3" />
    </multiRef>
    <multiRef id="id1" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="..." xsi:type="p719:RatingCommonData" xmlns:p719="http://input.rating.webservice.xxx.de">
      <requestdate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2010-12-24T09:45:09.531Z</requestdate>
      ...
```

I guess that the data contract serializer has problems deserializing the href's. Please note that the message I try to deserialize "by hand" was captured using my injected message inspector. In a "normal" call of the web service this message get deserialized without problems.

Comment: OK, now I see more of what you're trying to do. What you have in your window there is the entire SOAP message - with header and body and all. The "thing" you're trying to deserialize is the <p933:RatingResponse> element **inside** the <soapenv:Body> tag. I don't think you can (or should) deserialize the entire SOAP message - try to just grab whatever is contained in the SOAP body, and deserialize that - that's your actual **message payload** that would be returned from your WCF method call - everything else is just SOAP overhead....

Comment: I already did that. My test function uses `message.GetReaderAtBodyContents()` to skip the SOAP stuff. So the reader already points to the payload at node <p933:RatingResponse> when I call `dcs.ReadObject(readerAtBodyContents)`. The error I get lets me suspect that the deserializer just can't make the "hop" from href="#id0" to the multiref node with id="id0". This is why it barks at error in line 6, when it sees that it already reached the end tag of </p933:RatingResponse> but was expecting some fields that are actually encoded in those href nodes.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand what you're trying to ask and to do.... *based on an operation contract* ?? The **operation contract** is just an attribute you put on an operation / method call to mark it as a service method .... the operation contract doesn't do anything even remotely involved with serialization or deserialization..... do you mean how to deserialize an XML message using the `DataContractSerializer` which is the WCF default serializer??

Assuming you do really mean *HOWTO: deserialize a WCF message using the DataContractSerializer*, then try this: if you have the response XML from a service call that used the default WCF `DataContractSerializer`, you should be able to deserialize it like this (assuming you have your XML serialized response in a `xmlResponse` variable):

```
using(MemoryStream memStm = new MemoryStream())
using(StreamWriter stw = new StreamWriter(memStm))
{
   // write your response to the memory stream
   stw.Write(xmlResponse);
   stw.Flush();

   // "reset" memory stream
   memStm.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

   // setup DataContractSerializer     
   DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(YourDataType));

   // deserialize result XML into an instance of "YourDataType"
   var result = dcs.ReadObject(memStm);
}
```

Comment: Marc, thanks for answering. Sorry about not beeing more precise, this is because WCF is quite new to me. I appended more info to my original question. - Stefan

Answer (score 1):

For anyone in the future doing this. I had to manually read a WCF message out of the MSMSQ, and get the request object out of the MSMQ/WCF message envelope. Here's how:

Root code:

```
var q = new MessageQueue(@".\Private$\VishalQ;poison");

var allMessages = q.GetAllMessages().ToList();
var wcfRequests = allMessages.Select(ConvertToWcfRequest<ObjectChangedRequest>);
```

My contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWish
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ObjectChanged(ObjectChangedRequest request);
}
```

My Data Contract:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://x.namespaces.x-x.com/")]
public class ObjectChangedRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public OperationType OperationType { get; set; }
}
```

My message deserialization code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a WCF MSMQ message to a WCF request object.
    /// </summary>
    public static T ConvertToWcfRequest<T>(Message msmqMessage)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[msmqMessage.BodyStream.Length];
        msmqMessage.BodyStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)msmqMessage.BodyStream.Length);

        var envelopeStart = FindEnvelopeStart(buffer);

        using var msmqStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, envelopeStart, buffer.Length - envelopeStart);
        var encodingElement  = new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement();
        var wcfMessage       = encodingElement.CreateMessageEncoderFactory().Encoder.ReadMessage(msmqStream, int.MaxValue);
        var document         = new XmlDocument();

        document.Load(wcfMessage.GetReaderAtBodyContents());

        var realRoot        = document.FirstChild.FirstChild;
        using var wcfStream = new MemoryStream();
        using var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(wcfStream);

        realRoot.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
        xmlWriter.Flush();
        wcfStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var wcfSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T), realRoot.Name, "http://tempuri.org/"); //No idea why this has to be temp uri and not our namespace...

        return (T)wcfSerializer.ReadObject(wcfStream);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Locates the start of a WCF message within a MSMQ message.
    /// </summary>
    private static int FindEnvelopeStart(byte[] stream)
    {
        var position = 0;
        var previousByte = stream[position];

        for (position = 0; position < stream.Length; position++)
        {
            var currentByte = stream[position];

            //Some magic numbers that define the start of the WCF message envelope
            if (currentByte == 0x02 && previousByte == 0x56)
                break;

            previousByte = currentByte;
        }

        return position - 1;
    }
```